# I can't add a comment

Tags: support, stack-overflow, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

I know it is a repetitive question, but I couldn't find the solution.

I can't leave a comment on any posts/questions on Stack Overflow, but I can leave a comment on Meta Stack Overflow.

Why?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work - you need 50 rep

Comment: Why I'm limited?

Comment: @Behzad because you don't have 50 reputation. It is to prevent spam

Comment: thanks Mystical and Richard. Why I could leave a comment before but now not?

Comment: @Behzad: Read the linked post. You can always comment on your own questions (and answers to them), just not on those of others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different sites, with different privilege levels, and your rep on them is independent. On meta you need 1 rep to comment on any post and you have 1 rep so you're good. On stackoverflow you need 1 rep to comment on posts in your questions, but you need 50 rep to comment on posts of someone else's questions and you have 37, so you're almost there.

Comment: I could comment some month ago! those days I had fewer rep than now!

Comment: you can comment on your own questions and answers regardless of your rep. Perhaps in the past you were commenting on your own posts.