# Why I can't add comment to any question?

Tags: support, questions

For any question I see the following options only:

```
Edit|Share|Flag
```

So I cannot add a comment.

I can add comments to answers only.

Please explain why?

====================================

Update: I wish people could pay attention to posts like :

[Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users)

Take a look at upvotes on this post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have enough reputation.

Once you have 50 rep, you can comment on any post, not just on your questions/answers.

See the [comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) privilege.

Comment: OK Thanks. I'm new to this forum and didnt know this rule. I wonder why I should get 8 "DownVote"? To me this is a valid question.

Seems like some people cannot tolerate questions from the new members.

Comment: @SNash - See the [Voting is Different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) section of the help center.

Comment: I see this: "Meta is for questions about how stackoverflow website works". And my question was exactly in that topic. "In Meta downvote is when someone disagrees with the question" So 8 people disagreed with my question? I cannot how understand how 8 people disagree with this type of question!!! I really do think there should be a mechanism to disallow people to press the downvote without any reason. To me this will discourage the new members and make them use other sites. I'm a veteran member of Expert-Exchange and never seen this kind of behavior before. Anyway, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @SNash - Reputation is very much the basis of how these sites work and gaining the commenting privilege is one of the first ones people gain. It is very possible that people thought that the question lacked research effort and therefore downvoted it (note that the "normal" reasons for downvoting also apply on Meta). As for downvoting without commenting why - your suggesting has been brought up many many times before on meta and for different reasons will not be acted on (I do suggest searching for this here to see the different answers).

Comment: @SNash Oded is correct. You could simply type "can't add comments" (without quotes) in the search box here on Meta site. First result is http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146467/152859 which clearly explains the "problem".